# CKSDEV tools - problem with debugging

Tags: development, deployment, visual-studio

I use CKS devtools  version 1.1(latest).

Problem is: I installed tools and everything was ok relating to debug (VS2010 - Tools - CKSDEV -Attach to IIS Worker Processes) but after I changed deployment of my custom SP site template to another web application CKSDEV tools won't do debugging anymore. When I click on above link tools become "connected" to IIS wprocesses (everything seems ok), but I can't get inside of my breakpoints.

Any suggestion?

p.s. everything was deployed and activated ok, i did IIS resets, PC restarting, redefining place of breakpoints but that didn't helped. Also my collegue experience same problem on his pc after he changed web application and site collection path.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to hear you're having some issues.

Things to check are:

Can you attach using the normal Tools menu option within Visual Studio to the worker processes?

Is the target site url the same as the one you're attempting to debug?

An obvious one but is the project config in 'debug' mode?

If the above are ok and you can debug as expected through the OOB mechanisms when you use the CKSDev menu does it report any errors into the Output window? Also are the the processes shown as attached in the 'attach to process' OOB dialog.

A little bit of further info that would help is the OS version, SharePoint SKU, VS2010 SKU, any other add-ins or extensions installed in VS.

We support CKSDev through our CodePlex site here: http://cksdev.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

This is set up to alert the team when new issues/requests are submitted which helps us to get back to you quicker.

Regards,

Wes - CKSDev team

Comment: Hi Wes, and sorry for long waiting answer. It seems that problem isn't in CKSDEV tool. Now it seems that I had some problem with my development environment. Unfortunately, I don't know the reason but in meantime problem disappeared without any my specific action regarding that. Anyway thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem occasionally but rectified it by simply rebuilding the projects I want to debug.

This has happened when I modify & save files in another project (just an assembly, standard C# project) which is referenced by the project which is being deployed & tested (which is a SharePoint Project).

Comment: Thanx James, but rebuilding also didn't helped. I'll reinstall cksdev tools and see what will happen.